# Can you guess which DE's theme does my windows use? And how to recover my Ubuntu to fully use the GNOME theme?

Tags: gnome, themes

I've recently uninstalled the Deepin Desktop Evironment (DDE) from my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system, and now I'm using a strange theme that looks more like Arch/Kali Linux:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I restore the stock Ubuntu 20.04 theme?

Comment: Use the log out button and see what the drop down shows?

Comment: @Rinzwind A stock thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing (and uninstalling) alternative desktops will often mess up the default environment. There are a couple of options that may restore the default Gnome desktop but, be warned, this will restore *stock* settings. Any customisations that you have made will be wiped clear.

**Option 1: Reset Gnome**

The simplest is to reset the Gnome Desktop settings:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Reset Gnome:

   ```
   dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Do not do this via SSH. You must be on the machine itself.</sup>

**Option 2: Reinstall the Desktop Environment**

Sometimes a reinstallation of `ubuntu-desktop` is necessary:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Reinstall the Desktop Environment:

   ```
   sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   ```

One of these two ought to get you back to a default Ubuntu Gnome desktop.

Comment: `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`??? Done.